# Are double movement in Scrabble allowed?

Tags: scrabble

I am trying to put the word "ring" in scrabble in one move together with the the word er in the opposite direction. My girlfriend says it is cheating, is it ?

There is obviously a lot at stake here, so your help is very welcome !!!
I have so many pairs of socks to be washed ![image]

Comment: This is 100% legal. The close/duplicate target is for a different (and illegal, as answered) situation.

Comment: @Chris - could you confirm which letters you are playing on this turn? Just the "R, I, N, G" or are you playing the "E" on the triple letter square as well?

Answer (score 6):

As per the [rules](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules) as long as you are adding a valid letter to an existing word and all tiles are being placed along the same axis your play is ***valid***.

> **#3** Play passes to the left.
>
> - ... All letters played on a turn must be placed in one row across or down the board, to form at least one complete word.
>   If, at the same time, they touch others letters in adjacent rows, those must also form complete words, crossword fashion, with all such letters.
>   The player gets full credit for all words formed or modified on his or her turn.
>
> **#4** New words may be formed by:
>
> - Adding one or more letters to a word or letters already on the board.
> - Placing a word at right angles to a word already on the board.
>   The new word must use one of the letters already on the board ***or must add a letter to it***.
>   (See Turns 2, 3 and 4 below.)
> - Placing a complete word parallel to a word already played so that adjacent letters also form complete words.
>   (See Turn 5 in the Scoring Examples section below.)

Taking a look at the example turns you can see **Turn 3** closely resembles your play:
[image]